# Specific sorting to category by awk and bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Dear all i have one question.

I have the input like : (second column is only index)

```
chr1 1 30

chr1 2 40.5

chr1 3 30.5

chr1 4 41

chr2 10 60

chr2 15 40.1
```

And i want to get this:

```
           chr1  chr2

30 - 31     2     0

31 - 32     0     0

...

40 - 41     1     1 etc..
```

I need categorize data to each group from 30 to 60 per 1. From the input data I count all rows for chr1 which are contain in in the category 30-31 from $3. I have this code, but I do not understand where is problem: (some problem with loop)

```
samtools view /home/filip/Desktop/AMrtin\ Hynek/54321Odfiltrovany.bam | awk '{ n=length($10); print $3,"\t",NR,"\t", gsub(/[GCCgcs]/,"",$10)/n;}'  | awk '($3 <= 0.6 && $3 >= 0.3)' | awk '{print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",($3*100)}' > data.txt

for j in chr1 chr2 chr3 chr4 chr5 chr6 chr7 chr8 chr9 chr10 chr11 chr12 chr13 chr14 chr15 chr16 chr17 chr18 chr19 chr20 chr21 chr22
do

export $j

awk -v sop=$j  '{if($1 == $sop) print $0}' data.txt |
awk '{d=int($3)
      a[d]++
      if (NR==1) {min=d}
      min=(min>=d?d:min)
      max=(max>d?max:d)}
      END{for (i=min; i<=max; i++) print i, "-", i+1, a[i]+0}' ;
done
```

Part of code I made by help "fedorqui"

Comment: You should delete your question at biostars now.

Comment: What is that second column of desired output indicating? Where do those `2,0`, `0,       0`, and `1       1` values come from (and why do they have wildly inconsistent formatting in your example)?

Comment: It is count of rows which have $3 column values in the range 30 - 31 etc..and sorry for my formatting, It will be better for future posts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
!($1 in chrs) { chr[++c] = $1 ; chrs[$1]++ }
{
    val = int($3); 
    map[$1,val]++;
    min = (NR==1?val:min>=val?val:min);
    max = (max>val?max:val)
}
END {
    printf "\t\t"
    for (j=1; j<=c; j++) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, chr[j]
        sep = "\t"
    }
    print ""
    for (i=min; i<=max; i++) {
        printf "%d - %d\t", i, i+1
        for (j=1; j<=c; j++) {
            printf "\t%s", map[chr[j],i] + 0
        }
        print ""
    }
}' file
                chr1    chr2
30 - 31         2       0
31 - 32         0       0
32 - 33         0       0
...
38 - 39         0       0
39 - 40         0       0
40 - 41         1       1
41 - 42         1       0
42 - 43         0       0
...
59 - 60         0       0
60 - 61         0       1
```

- You increment the `chr` array by the order of chromosome seen.
- Rest stuff in the main block is pretty much your code except that we also create a `map` array that is indexed at chromosome and range having counts as its value.
- In the `END` block we first iterate over our `chr` array and print the chromosomes
- Then using our `min` and `max` variables we create a loop and print the values from our `map` array which is indexed at chromosome and the range.
- I have truncated some lines from the output. As you can see from the output it will print all numbers starting at `min` and ending at `max`.

Answer (score 3):

First, you could use :

```
for j in {1..22}; do
    chrj="char$j"
    # now you could use $chrj instead of $j in this loop
done
```

Instead of :

> ```
> for j in chr1 chr2 chr3 chr4 chr5 chr6 chr7 chr8 chr9 chr10 chr11 chr12 chr13 chr14 chr15 chr16 chr17 chr18 chr19 chr20 chr21 chr22
> do
>     # ...
> done
> ```

Then, you don't need to multiply calls to `awk` and pipes. Only one `awk` should be enough.

For example :

> ```
> ... | awk '($3 <= 0.6 && $3 >= 0.3)' | awk '{print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",($3*100)}'
> ```

Should be :

```
awk '($3 <= 0.6 && $3 >= 0.3){print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",($3*100)}'
# or
awk '{if ($3 <= 0.6 && $3 >= 0.3){print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",($3*100)}}'
```

Otherwise :

> ```
> export $j
> ```

What is the purpose of this `export` ?

I haven't read everything on your code but at this point many optimizations must be done !

Comment: thank for this optimizations, but it is still time does not work :-(

Comment: @FilipZembol I've corrected my second example with `awk` ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gawk, this should work. There's a filter for $1 that should handle everything you were doing with $j (unless you truly need only chr1..chr22, in which case it should still be possible to develop a regex for it).

```
BEGIN {
  for(i = 30; i <= 60; i++) {
    rstring = i " - " i + 1;
    rows[rstring] = 0;
  }
}
$1 ~ /^chr[0-9][0-9]?$/ {
  row = int($3) " - " int($3) + 1;
  columns[$1] = 0;
  rows[row] = 0;
  data[row][$1] += 1;
  rowwidth = length(row) > rowwidth ? length(row) : rowwidth;
  colwidth = length($1) > colwidth ? length($1) : colwidth;
 }
END {
  rowheader = "%-" (rowwidth * 2) "s";
  colheader = "%" colwidth "s\t";
  dataformat = "%" int(colwidth / 2) "d\t";

  asorti(columns, sortedcolumns);
  asorti(rows, sortedrows);

  printf rowheader, "";
  for(c in sortedcolumns) printf "%s\t", sortedcolumns[c];
  print "";

  for(r in sortedrows) {
    printf rowheader, sortedrows[r];
    for(c in sortedcolumns)
      printf dataformat, data[sortedrows[r]][sortedcolumns[c]];
    print ""
  }
}
```

Running it with `gawk -f [scriptfile from above] < data.txt` should produce something like:

`chr1      chr2
30 - 31        2         0
31 - 32        0         0
 . . .
39 - 40        0         0
40 - 41        1         1
41 - 42        1         0
42 - 43        0         0
 . . .
59 - 60        0         0
60 - 61        0         1`

Comment: I receive from this error :awk: groupindleGC.awk:11:   data[row][$1] += 1;
awk: groupindleGC.awk:11:            ^ syntax error
awk: groupindleGC.awk:30:       printf dataformat, data[sortedrows[r]][sortedcolumns[c]];
awk: groupindleGC.awk:30:                                             ^ syntax error
awk: groupindleGC.awk:30:       printf dataformat, data[sortedrows[r]][sortedcolumns[c]];

Comment: I believe that is an *awk* error... can you try with *gawk* instead?

Answer (score 2):

**Following can be used if you want to use Perl**

```
perl -ane '
$h{$F[0]}{int $F[2]}++;
push @range, int $F[2]; 
}{
@range = sort @range; 
print "\t\t", join "\t", sort { $a cmp $b } keys %h; print "\n";
for $i ($range[0] .. $range[-1]) {
print "$i - ", $i + 1, "\t\t"; 
print $h{$_}{$i} + 0, "\t" for sort { $a cmp $b } keys %h; print "\n"
}' file
```

**Output should be like this**

```
                chr1    chr2
30 - 31         2       0
31 - 32         0       0
32 - 33         0       0
33 - 34         0       0
34 - 35         0       0
35 - 36         0       0
36 - 37         0       0
37 - 38         0       0
38 - 39         0       0
39 - 40         0       0
40 - 41         1       1
41 - 42         1       0
42 - 43         0       0
43 - 44         0       0
44 - 45         0       0
45 - 46         0       0
46 - 47         0       0
47 - 48         0       0
48 - 49         0       0
49 - 50         0       0
50 - 51         0       0
51 - 52         0       0
52 - 53         0       0
53 - 54         0       0
54 - 55         0       0
55 - 56         0       0
56 - 57         0       0
57 - 58         0       0
58 - 59         0       0
59 - 60         0       0
```